# How to fix Unable to replicate a view or function because the referenced objects or columns are not present on the Subscriber.?

Tags: sql-server, replication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWlIL.png)Transactional Replication Errors:

> Unable to replicate a view or function because the referenced objects or columns are not present on the Subscriber.

Command attempted:

```sql
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VIEW_INVOICE_CODE_LIST_4368_001_20210630_125653] AS SELECT DISTINCT INVO_CODE FROM TEMP_VIEW_SALES_REPORT_4368_001_20210630_125651
```

> (Transaction sequence number: 0x001F4D4700001538004500000000, Command ID: 10161)

Error messages:

> Unable to replicate a view or function because the referenced objects or columns are not present on the Subscriber. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20164)
> Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20164
> Invalid object name 'TEMP_VIEW_SALES_REPORT_4368_001_20210630_125651'. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 208)
> Get help: http://help/208
> Unable to replicate a view or function because the referenced objects or columns are not present on the Subscriber. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL2759)
> Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL2759

Comment: A `VIEW` selecting from a "TEMP" view sounds like the problem is actually being described quite well to you here; the `TEMP VIEW" doesn't exist on the subscriber; likely because, as it's name suggests, you're treating it like a pseudo-temporary object. This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) if I am honest.

Comment: The replication of your view failed because objects it uses are not present. So did you mark this other view for replication?